# How to Remove/Register Suffix on Laravel Route?

Tags: filter, routes, laravel

**EDIT: See below for my current problem. The top portion is a previous issue that I've solved but is somewhat related**

I need to modify the input values passed to my controller before it actually gets there. I am building a web app that I want to be able to support multiple request input types (JSON and XML initially). I want to be able to catch the input BEFORE it goes to my restful controller, and modify it into an appropriate StdClass object.

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to intercept and modify that input. Help?

For example, I'd like to be able to have filters like this:

```
Route::filter('json', function()
{
    //modify input here into common PHP object format
});

Route::filter('xml', function()
{
    //modify input here into common PHP object format
});

Route::filter('other', function()
{
    //modify input here into common PHP object format
});

Route::when('*.json', 'json'); //Any route with '.json' appended uses json filter
Route::when('*.xml', 'xml'); //Any route with '.json' appended uses json filter
Route::when('*.other', 'other'); //Any route with '.json' appended uses json filter
```

Right now I'm simply doing a `Input::isJson()` check in my controller function, followed by the code below - note that this is a bit of a simplification of my code.

```
$data = Input::all();
$objs = array();
foreach($data as $key => $content)
{
    $objs[$key] = json_decode($content);
}
```

**EDIT: I've actually solved this**, but have another issue now. Here's how I solved it:

```
Route::filter('json', function()
{
    $new_input = array();
    if (Input::isJson())
    {
        foreach(Input::all() as $key => $content)
        {
            //Do any input modification needed here
            //Save it in $new_input
        }
        Input::replace($new_input);
    }
    else
    {
        return "Input provided was not JSON";
    }
});

Route::when('*.json', 'json'); //Any route with '.json' appended uses json filter
```

The issue I have now is this: The path that the Router attempts to go to after the filter, contains `.json` from the input URI. The only option I've seen for solving this is to replace `Input::replace($new_input)` with

```
$new_path = str_replace('.json', '', Request::path());
Redirect::to($new_path)->withInput($new_input);
```

This however leads to 2 issues. Firstly I can't get it to redirect with a `POST` request - it's always a `GET` request. Second, the data being passed in is being flashed to the session - I'd rather have it available via the `Input` class as it would be with `Input::replace()`.

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the second issue as well - but it involved a lot of extra work and poking around... I'm not sure if it's the best solution, but it allows for suffixing routes similar to how you would prefix them.

Here's the github commit for how I solved it: 
https://github.com/pcockwell/AuToDo/commit/dd269e756156f1e316825f4da3bfdd6930bd2e85

In particular, you should be looking at:

```
app/config/app.php
app/lib/autodo/src/Autodo/Routing/RouteCompiler.php
app/lib/autodo/src/Autodo/Routing/Router.php
app/lib/autodo/src/Autodo/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php
app/routes.php
composer.json
```

After making these modifications, I needed to run `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan optimize`. The rest of those files are just validation for my data models and the result of running those 2 commands.

I didn't split the commit up because I'd been working on it for several hours and just wanted it in.

I'm going to hopefully look to extend the suffix tool to allow an array of suffixes so that any match will proceed. For example,

```
Route::group(array('suffix' => array('.json', '.xml', 'some_other_url_suffix')), function()
{
    // Controller for base API function.
    Route::controller('api', 'ApiController');
});
```

And this would ideally accept any call matching

```
{base_url}/api/{method}{/{v1?}/{v2?}/{v3?}/{v4?}/{v5?}?}{suffix}`
```

Where:

- `base_url` is the domain base url
- `method` is a function defined in `ApiController`
- `{/{v1?}/{v2?}/{v3?}/{v4?}/{v5?}?}` is a series of up to 5 optional variables as are added when registering a controller with `Route::controller()`
- `suffix` is one of the values in the suffix array passed to `Route::group()`

This example in particular should accept all of the following (assuming `localhost` is the base url, and the methods available are `getMethod1($str1 = null, $str2 = null)` and `postMethod2()`):

- `GET` request to `localhost/api/method1.json`
- `GET` request to `localhost/api/method1.xml`
- `GET` request to `localhost/api/method1some_other_url_suffix`
- `POST` request to `localhost/api/method2.json`
- `POST` request to `localhost/api/method2.xml`
- `POST` request to `localhost/api/method2some_other_url_suffix`
- `GET` request to `localhost/api/method1/hello/world.json`
- `GET` request to `localhost/api/method1/hello/world.xml`
- `GET` request to `localhost/api/method1/hello/worldsome_other_url_suffix`

The last three requests would pass `$str1 = 'hello'` and `$str2 = 'world'` to `getMethod1` as parameters.

**EDIT: The changes to allow multiple suffixes was fairly easy**. Commit located below (please make sure you get BOTH commit changes to get this working):
https://github.com/pcockwell/AuToDo/commit/864187981a436b60868aa420f7d212aaff1d3dfe

Eventually, I'm also hoping to submit this to the [laravel/framework](https://github.com/laravel/framework) project.